# I want an E notation double variable to go to string, but...?

Tags: java, string, double, println

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

double amount = 0;
int bits = -1;

////////////////////////////
//Enter the amount of bits//
////////////////////////////
        bits += 64;
////////////////////////////


for(int i = 0; i <bits;i++)
{
  amount += pow(2,i);


}
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
String amount1 = String.format(df.format(amount));
println("number: ", amount1);
int namelength = amount1.length();
println(namelength, " digits");
```

If i fill in 64 in line 12 then what i want is for the outcome to be is 9223372036854775808 but it out puts this 9.223372e+18.
Then i try and convert that double '9.223372e+18' to a string with the appropriate decimal numbers but in stead of giving the '808' at the end of the double but it has '000'. What would i have to do to make it give me the 808 in stead?

Comment: A [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) only has 53 bits of precision, so it simply *cannot* store 63 bits of information accurately.

Comment: @Andreas what other variable would i be able to use then?

Comment: `long` has 63 bits + 1 sign bit. `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` can store much more, both with full precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your code can be simplified a lot and there is no need to double because of pow. double use IEEE and they didn't store exactly in memory. you can use something like this:

```
long amount = 1;
int bits = -1;

bits += 64;
amount = (amount << bits) - 1;
System.out.println("number: " + amount);
```

except it output one value less that what you expect. (and I think because of number range in long, we have range like this [-128, 127] for two's complement)   I think you write it wrong because I check and it must be that. However I don't know is it what you want or not.

Comment: If OP is trying to fill a 32-bit int with 1s, `int amount = ~0` (or just -1) would be easier.